# Exponential and uniform stability

Tags: control-theory

I really don't understand how resolve this exercise...with Lyapunoff? can someone help me? Thanks

Consider the state equation:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}x(t)= A(t)x(t),         \: x(\tau)=x_0
$$

$$
A(t) =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & k(t)  \\
    0 & -1  \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$

(a) Assume that $k(t)$ is constant over time, that is $k(t) = \tilde{k}$ for $t ≥ \tau$. For
what value of scalar constant $\tilde{k}$ is the system exponentially stable?

(b) Is the state equation uniformly stable for all scalar functions $k(t)$? If
so, provide a proof. If not, provide a counterexample.

Comment: CAPITAL LETTERS ARE CONSIDERED AS SHOUTING. WHY DO YOU SHOUT AT US

Comment: what are the eigenvalues of $A$ if $k(t)$ is constant?

Comment: @obareey -1. I think that for all values of scalar constant ktilde the system in exponentially stable..are u agree?

Comment: @nenè Yes, since eigenvalues are negative for any constant $\tilde{k}$.

Comment: @obareey and what about request b? I mean for the uniformly stability..

Comment: Since it bocomes time invariant, stability implies uniform stability.

Comment: @nene at least give a review about my answer !

Comment: @obareey I think that for the request b) the state equation is not uniformly stable for all scalar function k(t)..Are you agree?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misread the question, it is uniformly stable for all _constant_ functions.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part here is the solution :

$$X'= AX$$
Taking the Laplace on both sides , we get : 
$$sX(s)-x_0 = AX(s)$$
After some re-arrangement we will get it as :
$$ (sI-A)X(s) = x_0$$

Here $I$ is $2\times 2$ identity matrix . Therefore putting the values of $A$, $I$ and $x_0$ . Here $x_0$ is $2\times 1$ matrix write it as 
\begin{bmatrix}
         x_{01} \\
         x_{02} \\
\end{bmatrix}
Now using these values of $ A,I$ and $x_0$ you will get
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Taking the laplace inverse we get :
[image]
Sow we see that for any value $k$ in the real domain , it is exponentially stable .
But from my proof we can see that if $k(t)$ is $e^{t^2}$ it will not be stable

Comment: but this is for question a and b?

Comment: I have done it putting $k$ when $k$ is constant it will always be exponentially stable, when $k(t)$ is suppose $e^{t^2}$ it will not be stable . that answers (b) part .

Comment: ok! I got it! Thanks!!!!